# Ruby : As a file is getting written; write those line to a different file

Tags: ruby, file

Due to some OS restrictions I am not able to install ruby and mysql on my prod node. I have to process a Log file written on that node. So I planning to write the contents of the log file to a different file as its written to the log and work on that new file.

```
def watch_for(file)

       f = File.open(file,"r")
       f.seek(0,IO::SEEK_END)

       while true do

             select([f])
             line = f.gets

             open('myfile.out', 'a+') { |s|

              s.puts "#{line}"

                }

             end
       end
```

But this seems to failing;  Any help to this is much appreciated.

Comment: "this seems to failing" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* fails? *How* does it fail? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: There is no error; my "myfile.out" file just gets blanks lines filling in when I pass something into the "File.open(file,"r")".

Comment: Rather than write it in Ruby, use `tail -f "file" >> myfile.out ` and let the system handle it. It'll be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the inout @theTinMan

Comment: If you don't have ruby on your production node, how are you running ruby on your production node?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a great idea to reopen the output file each time through the loop. If you are just planning on appending and not reading the file, use `'a'` rather than '`a+'` for the IO mode. Also, there's no good reason to use string interpolation like `"#{line}"`. I rewrote the method to open each file just once:

```
def watch_for(file)

  f = File.open(file,"r")
  f.seek(0,IO::SEEK_END)
  s = File.open('myfile.out', 'a')

  while true do
    s.write(f.readline)
  end
end
```

Probably better if this isn't a method at all since there's no way to exit except to kill the process. And, of course, you can just use `tail -f $file >> myfile.out` as mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416332/ruby-as-a-file-is-getting-written-write-those-line-to-a-different-file#comment75848027_44416332).